# Slider in django website using bootstrap4 carousel

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, carousel

i want to create a carousel slider in my django website where i could easily add/remove images from my admin panel.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for obj in projects %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <div class="carousel-item active  ">
            {% else %}
                <div class="carousel-item  ">
            {% endif %}
            <img class="d-block w-100 h-50" class="h-50 d-inline-block" src="{{ obj.thumbnail.url}}" alt="{{obj.title}}">
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        {% for obj in sliderview %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}" class="active"></li>
            {% else %}
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}"></li>

            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for obj in sliderview %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <div class="carousel-item active  ">
            {% else %}
                <div class="carousel-item  ">
            {% endif %}
            <img class="d-block w-100 h-50" class="h-50 d-inline-block" src="{{ obj.thumbnail.url}}" alt="{{obj.title}}">
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but is causing an extra indicator to show up for me. For example, if I have three images, I see four indicators.

Answer (score 0):

your html template is normal. You need to create model like this:

```
class Carousel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
```

in your admin.py:

```
...
admin.site.register(Carousel)
```

in view:

```
...
projects = Carousel.objects.all()
return render(request, 'template.html', {'projects': projects})
```

Comment: i am doing the same, i  have one of the model for slider registered with admin along with view as you can see im trying to fetch images and title that i have added using the admin